# Use SQL Cursor to queryout to csv file

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, cursor, bcp

I have to create a sql script that will loop through a Customer table and export the customer data such as address and purchase history (currently in separate tables) to a .csv file. The customer table has 2500 customers, so essentially it  would have to be 2500 .csv files. Also, would love to name these csv files based on the customer name.

I think the best bet is to use bcp and cursor to loop through the customer table and grab the relevant information from the address and purchase history tables. I am used to writing simple queries and not written anything described above. Would appreciate insight/samples!

Thank You!

Comment: Have you considered SSIS?  Although this can be done with xp_cmdshell and BCP, T-SQL alone isn't really the right tool for this job.

Comment: Will your code (to access the DB) be on windows or linux ?

Comment: I did try it in SSIS, but I have 2500 customers' data to export. Would I create 2500 ssis packages? Code will be on Windows. Perhaps its faster through Query Analyzer. How would I do this through SSIS, i need to export data and name each file according to the customer name.